# Expanding an outline group in Excel prompts for password to unprotect the sheet

Tags: excel, excel-365

I created an Excel workbook for my client.  They distribute this workbook to their clients by allowing them to download it off of their website.  This is a ".xlsx" workbook (no VBA allowed, per my Client's parameters).

Each worksheet is password protected.  Some worksheets have had outline groups setup.  The protection on the worksheet allows for these groups to be expanded and collapsed.  This works fine on my PC, my Client's PC, and the majority of their clients as well.

However, a couple of their clients are getting the following message when trying to expand a group:
"You cannot use this command on a protected sheet. To use this command, you must first unprotect the sheet (Review tab, Changes group, Unprotect Sheet button). You may be prompted for a password."  When they click OK on this message, Excel then prompts them for the password to unprotect the worksheet.

The following worksheet protection settings are checked and use a password:

-Select unlocked cells

-Format rows

-Edit objects

-Edit scenarios

-(all other settings are unchecked)

Protect Workbook is also enabled and uses a password.

Does anyone know why some users are getting this message?  The majority of users are not.  Please also know that the groupings are for rows only.  No columns are grouped.

The workbook must remain a VBA free workbook.  At the time of this message, my client has not allowed me to share the workbook with this discussion group.

Thank you for your feedback.  It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tagged excel-365. Are all your clients using latest excel version and how are you sure about that. Also "my client has not allowed me to share the workbook with this discussion group" - just clear sensitive data and show template

Comment: I tagged Excel 365 because that is what I use, but cannot be sure what version of Excel my client's clients are using.  And unfortunately, neither can they.  Is it possible there are versions of Excel that do not work properly with this worksheet protection?  Also, it is not the data that is sensitive in the Excel file, I just am not allowed to share it.  I am working on obtaining that permission.